# How to group by year when I have a columns named date in the format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, sql

I have a table in which a date column is there in the format dd/mm/yyyy. I have an accordion in which I want to show years like 2014 then 2013 and so on. When I click on 2014(my accordion) it will expand. If I had a column containing only year then it would have been easier. Now I am confused whether to simply create a columns named year. or do something in php to get this think working.

Basically I have to display a UI which customers purchase history will be shown. Year wise. When I click on 2014 the pane would expand and inside, all his invoices would be visible.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you need only year???

Comment: Just do simple `>` and `<` with `(YEAR)-01-01` in your WHERE clause

Comment: Inside your SQL query, select only the year from the date column (if you want the year to be displayed from your date column)

Comment: I have edited my question and could you guyz please be a little more specific? Plz

Comment: It sounds like you might be storing your date as a string and not, well, a date!

Comment: Yes I m storing it as varchar

Comment: First step, store dates as dates, not varchars: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/choosing-types.html

Comment: If I use jquery datepicker would the dates get saved in that format?

Comment: You might want to read this article: http://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-dates-and-times/

Comment: @Professor take a look on the jquery datepicker documentation, you can change the format of date according to need. also is in `yyyy-mm-dd` format that a date datatype accept in mysql.

Comment: this is a really simple question, which can be answered by searching the internet, too. Just use DateTime on MySQL and Date on others and extract the year from the date column with the YEAR function as described on my websites. So, -1

Comment: @alpham8 My question was how do I group by year and at the same time show all the rows associated with that year in the expandable panel. When you do not understand the question just dont bother. Scroll down and see how Bryan understood the question.

Comment: @Professor So what´s the problem with using Date/DateTime datatype in your database or simply an integer value for the year? Neither char or varchar makes sense in that case. Your correct answer below is just a workaround of something which can be done by the database. If it´s possible, use the database functions for manipulating/filtering data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the results with php to get your desired results.

```
$result = some_query_result(); //however you're retreiving the data
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $dateArray = explode('/', $row['date']); //whatever the date field is.
    $year = end($dateArray);
    //now you have the year - do with it as you please.
    //maybe create an array containing the data or something
    $theData[$year][] = $row; //now you'll have data keyed by year in the array
}
```

Don't know exactly what you're doing with it after or how you're creating the html, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: I have managed to group by year. How do I retrieve the rows data after grouping?

Comment: I have made two entries each for 2012, 2013 and 2014 but when I use print_r($theData[$year]) it does not returns multiple row data. It always returns a single row. How can I get all the rows associated with the specific year

Comment: you must have done $theData[$year] = instead of $theData[$year][] =

Comment: the way I wrote it $theData[$year] should be an array of arrays where $theData[$year][0] would be a row of data, $theData[$year][1] another data row, and so on...

Comment: either that or you're printing it in the loop and dying or exiting or something

Comment: No Problem, glad you got it.

Answer (score 2):

You can `GROUP BY` the result of a function. I would prefer [YEAR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) since AFAIK it's the fastest way possible. Year will only extract the YEAR portion of the date.
Here is an example on how to do that:

```
SELECT date_column FROM ... GROUP BY YEAR(date_column)
```

*Note that conversion is slow and will result in very slow queries. Instead you might want to have a date column which will force the use of date indexing instead of string indexing and will result in a much better performance.*

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( `date` , '%Y' ) AS d_yr
FROM tablename
GROUP BY `d_yr` ASC
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( `date` , '%Y' ) ASC
```

Comment: I don't beleive this will work, as the date is stored as a `varchar` not `date`

Comment: No, DATE_FORMAT gives a string froma a date http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: I have converted my date column from varchar to date and I have managed to save it in the required format.